# Writing output names to a string adding extra characters

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am setting up an application that have rooms for its users. The only way to group these users is by listing their names in the following fashion:

```
Host IN ('Fist1 Last1', 'Fist2 Last2', 'Fist3 Last3')
```

I would like to output the names of the users in a given OU in the format inside of the parentheses above. Just 'Fist1 Last1', 'Fist2 Last2', 'Fist3 Last3'.

```
Get-ADuser -searchbase "OU=HQ,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM" -filter {enabled -eq "True"} | Select-Object -Property name
```

How can I have that output in 'first last', 'first last', 'first last', etc....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I think this should work:

```
(Get-ADuser -searchbase "OU=HQ,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM" -filter {enabled -eq "True"} |
  ForEach-Object { "'{0} {1}'" -f $_.GivenName,$_.Surname }) -join ','
```